# How to decode an object writed in php in python

Tags: python

I have an object returned from php in the following way

```
{"product_specification"=>[{"key"=>"Number of Contents in Sales Package", "value"=>"Pack of 3"}, {"key"=>"Fabric", "value"=>"Cotton Lycra"}, {"key"=>"Type", "value"=>"Cycling Shorts"}, {"key"=>"Pattern", "value"=>"Solid"}, {"key"=>"Ideal For", "value"=>"Women's"}, {"value"=>"Gentle Machine Wash in Lukewarm Water, Do Not Bleach"}, {"key"=>"Style Code", "value"=>"ALTHT_3P_21"}, {"value"=>"3 shorts"}]}
```

I tried to use json.loads but it doesn't work
Any ideas how I could use the data from it?

Comment: Change your php code to *actually* return JSON. That is the only reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

object_str = """{"product_specification"=>[{"key"=>"Number of Contents in Sales Package", "value"=>"Pack of 3"}, {"key"=>"Fabric", "value"=>"Cotton Lycra"}, {"key"=>"Type", "value"=>"Cycling Shorts"}, {"key"=>"Pattern", "value"=>"Solid"}, {"key"=>"Ideal For", "value"=>"Women's"}, {"value"=>"Gentle Machine Wash in Lukewarm Water, Do Not Bleach"}, {"key"=>"Style Code", "value"=>"ALTHT_3P_21"}, {"value"=>"3 shorts"}]}"""
object_str = object_str.replace('"=>"','":"').replace('"=>','":')
object_json = json.loads(object_str)
print(object_json)
```

Explanation:

1. Convert your php key into a python doc string
2. replace the php symbols for dicts/objects with python symbols.
3. use json loads to convert docstring into dict/object.

if you need help converting your php example into a python docstring try this maybe:

```
object_str = '"""'+phpobject+'"""'
```

Comment: Will obviously not work if anything contains a => in the strings. Generally a bad idea to convert data that way.

Comment: @luk2302 you are right! I wasn't paying attention. What about `object_str = object_str.replace('"=>"','":"').replace('"=>','":')` ? I updated the answer to reflect the new attempt. I am now looking for the qoutes along the php key delemiter so that its not JUST looking for => but it will look for "=>" instead and replace with ":". Of course this wont work if there are spaces. lol but I could just make the replace statement like this then ('" => "', '" : "' )

Comment: No simple string replacement will ever work because whatever string you are looking for can equally likely appear within the actual keys and values.

Comment: Ah! that is very true. - In that case you have to do as you mentioned and return the data in a JSON format on the PHP side.